# Program that tells user whether one number is evenly divisible by another

Tags: c, newline, scanf

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int num2;
    printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    scanf("%i\n",&num);
    scanf("%i\n",&num2);

    if (num % num2 == 0){
        printf("%i is evenly divided by %i",num,num2);
    }
    else {
        printf("%i is not evenly divided by %i", num, num2);

    }
        return 0;
}
```

When i run the above code in terminal this is what happens

```
Enter two numbers
3
4


dsfa
3 is not evenly divided by 4
```

I entered the two numbers, but then nothing happens until i enter some form of text(thats what the random "dsfa" is), and then the program will return with the correct `printf` statement. It has to be text i cannot just hit the enter button(thats where the blank spaces come from). Why is this program not returning what i intend it to, right after the user enters two numbers?

Comment: @ShaZiv would you mind explaining why?

Comment: @ShaZiv this achieved the same result

Comment: Sorry about the last post, I miss read some part...
Anyway, it's because of the `\n` in the `scanf`

Comment: @turbulencetoo It makes more sense to use `%d` if you are expecting to work with decimal numbers. `%i` is a more flexible format specifier that will interpret numbers beginning with `0` as octal and `0x` as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3):

An `'\n'` or a whitespace character in the format string consumes an entire (possibly empty) sequence of whitespace characters in the input.

So the `scanf` only returns when it encounters the next non-whitespace character, or the end of the input stream.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `'\n'` (and this is true for any whitespace in the format string) in the format string of `scanf` will match any number of whitespace characters. It will exit only when it encounters a non-whitespace character.

Also, `%i` conversion specifier means that `scanf` will read an integer. If the input number contains a leading `0`, the number will be read as an octal number (base `8`). If the imput number contains `0x` or `0X`, the number will be read as a hexadecimal number (in base `16`). The number will be read as decimal integer otherwise. Make sure that you really want `%i` instead of `%d` which always reads a decimal integer.

Please note that `%i` skips leading whitespace characters anyway. So, you don't need `'\n'` in the format string of `scanf` to match a newline.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    int num2;
    printf("Enter two numbers\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    scanf("%i", &num2);

    if (num % num2 == 0){
        printf("%i is evenly divided by %i\n", num, num2);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("%i is not evenly divided by %i\n", num, num2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use  `'\n'` in the `scanf()` function.If you want to have a newline after an input then you can add  `printf("\n")` after the `scanf()` function as follows (Note that I've commented out the `printf()` statements),

```
  printf("Enter two numbers\n");

  scanf("%i", &num);

  // printf("\n"); 

  scanf("%i", &num2);

  // printf("\n");
```

Otherwise just remove `'\n'` from your scanf() functions and just write:

```
 scanf("%i", &num);
 scanf("%i", &num2);
```

or you can input both values in one `scanf()` like this :

```
scanf("%i%i",&num,&num2);
```

whatever you like!

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `\n` or any extra white space in scanf(). use

```
scanf("%i",&num);
scanf("%i",&num2);
```

program will execute right.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'\n'` in your `scanf();` functions or just in second `scanf();` function.
You can use only one `scanf();` function to read both numbers.

```
scanf("%i %i", &num, &num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

never use `\n` in the `scanf()`.

`\n` is an escape sequence which is used for some results like newline, tabspace etc.

[Go here for more info about Escape Sequence](http://www.zaketeck.com/2013/02/Escape-Sequence-In-C-Language.html)

So, just remove the `\n` in the `scanf()` function. Other then that, everything is right..